# Why do I receive syntax error while printing format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-import, python-3.7

```
Person = { 'name' : " Jehn", ' age':23}
Sentence= f' My name is {person ['name']} and i am {person['age']} years old.'
```

Comment: f'' doesn't work in python 2

Comment: Use python 3... or fix your tags and post a proper [mcve]. If you're on python 3.7 you might have to swap ' for " inside the f-string.

Comment: Well, Python variable names are case sensitive, and in the code quoted above you are defining 'Person' with a capital 'P' and then referring to it with a small 'p' and that is not the same variable.

Comment: @Nathan it says both.

Comment: How do you run your program? From the commandline using `python`? What exactly is the error message you get? There is more information we need to help you.
Also note that there are multiple versions of Python. The notation with the `f` in front of a string (the quotes) was introduced in Python version 3.6

Comment: @JonasDrotleff i am using python 3.7. it displays syntax error message and highlight ( name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the type of quoting in the format string so it is wrapped with double-quotes like this:

```
person = { 'name' : " Jehn", 'age':23} 
sentence = f" My name is {person ['name']} and i am {person['age']} years old."
```

Note that there was also space in `' age'` which could be missed easily.  Also, I changed the variables to be all lowercase letters to be more Pythonic and consistent.